# NPM Install, Test, CI without devDependencies

Tags: npm

Our build pipeline is `npm install` -> `npm test` -> Zip the artifact.

This however means our artifact contains all devDependencies. If we do `npm --only=production` we lose the devDependencies but `npm test` will fail.

How can we generated a **tested** artifact *without* devDependencies? Do we just have to trust that our app will run without the devDependencies after we test with them?

BONUS question: How should `npm ci` fit into this workflow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will want to follow have your process to the effect of the following:

First, you need to "install with all dependencies".

```
npm install
```

Then do your tests.

```
npm test
```

Then "prune" your dev dependencies as below, as detailed in the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/prune.html) doing this "will remove the packages specified in your devDependencies".

```
npm prune --production
```

Regarding `npm ci` you can simply use this in place of `npm install` if you have a package-lock.json, see [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53325242/2344348) for an explanation of the difference.